# Angular Flexbox: how to set max width of a div

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I'm using [Angular Flexlayout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) (based on FlexBox) to add responsiveness to my application.

Is it possible to set a **max-width** to a HTML element?

Example:

```
<div fxFlex.gt-md="70" fxLayout.lt-lg="100"> 
<!-- I want this div to have a maximum width of 1750px. 
Setting max-width has no effect. How can I achieve this? -->
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to link your CSS file below the Angular CSS file?

Answer (score 19):

The solution is to use the "shrink" and "grow" value of the FxFlex tag. 
Grow: How to grow the element
Shrink: How to shrink the element
Initial: Initial value

Examples:

```
fxFlex="grow shrink initial"
fxFlex="0 1 70" <- Will not grow, will shrink 1:1, initial value of 70%
fxFlex="0 1 1750px" <- Will not grow, will shrink 1:1, initial value of 1750px
```

[Documentation here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlex-API)

Comment: Beautiful solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I think the simplest solution is adding a CSS class :

```
<div class="content" fxLayout="row" fxFlexFill>
  <div fxFlex="15" class="max-width">
    first-section
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="30" class="sec2">
    second-section
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="55" class="sec3">
    third-section
  </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS class:

```
.max-width{
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 1750px;
}
.sec2{
    background-color: blue;
}
.sec3{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```